# javascript on page can i store to allow javascript in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

On my page i have some javascript and ofcourse IE has prevented the page from running scripts or activex controls. if they click to allow the scripts to run can i store that in a cookie?

I am willing to read and write the cookie in which ever language that would allow this.

Comment: Storing code in a cookie is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE normally only prevents javascript and activex controls when running the file locally. Once you put the file on a server somewhere you will not be prompted for run permission.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are data, you can store executable code in them but they can't execute the code themselves. You can, for example, store JavaScript in a cookie and `eval` it on a subsequent request, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: your answer is very informative, my problem was i was just testing the file on my computer didn't realize that made a difference.